# JAVA Refactor methods for crud

Tags: java, refactoring, crud, mapper

I have an entity called Travel which has list of cost center i have created a code for handling CRUD operation for cost centers

```
protected void assignCostCenter(CostCenterDTO costCenterDTO, Travel travel, Long detailsId) throws BusinessException {
    CostCenter costCenter = null;
    if (costCenterDTO.getCostCenters() != null) {
        Center center = commonDao.find(costCenterDTO.getCostCenters().getId());
        costCenter = costCenterDTOMapper.mapToDTO(costCenterDTO.getCostCenters(), travel, detailsId, center);
        if (costCenter != null && !travel.getCostCenters().contains(costCenter)) {
            travel.getCostCenters().add(costCenter);
        }
    } else {
        travel.setCostCenters(travel.getCostCenters().stream().filter(costCenter1 -> !(costCenter1.getDetailId().equals(detailsId))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

And in the mapper

```
 public CostCenter mapToCostCenter(CostCenterDTO costCenterDTO, Travel travel, Long claimDetail, Center center) throws BusinessException {
        CostCenter costCenter = new CostCenter();
        CostCenter costCenterToUpdate = travel.getCostCenters()
                .stream()
                .filter(costCenter1 -> costCenter1.getDetailId().equals(claimDetail))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        if (costCenterToUpdate == null) {
            costCenter.setCenter(center);
            costCenter.setTravel(travel);
            costCenter.setDetailId(claimDetail);
        } else {
            costCenterToUpdate.setCenter(center);
            return costCenterToUpdate;
        }
        return costCenter;
    }
```

The functionality is that if new CostCenter is assigned i fetch Center from db which was assigned and pass to mapper in mapper i call travel.getCostCenters to see if there is no costCenter already assigned with same detail id if there is i just update it if there is no i create new and return, and add to list if doesn't exist, also if CostCenterDTO comes as null then i remove from list costCenter by detailId, but my question is how i could refactor it because it doesn't look tidy?

Comment: I think this will be more suited for a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I see here regarding **readability**: violation of the [SLA](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction) principle.

Meaning: it *really* helps to not have ifs within ifs. Instead, you write small helper methods to do such work; so that each method only contains elements of the "same" abstraction layer.

Beyond that; on a style level: I *prefer* to "return" over "else"; like:

```
 if (costCenterToUpdate == null) {
   return updateCostCenter(center, travel, claimDetail);   
 }

 costCenterToUpdate.setCenter(center);
 return costCenterToUpdate;
```